# file data seems to be corrupted when reading file as a string

Tags: c#, file, streamreader

I'm trying to read a file as string. But it seems that the data is corrupted.

```
string filepaths = Files[0].FullName;
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(filepaths);
string datas = myFile.ReadToEnd();
```

but in datas, it contains "pk0101" etc instead of original data. I'm doing this so I can replace a placeholder with this string data,datas. And finally when I replace,gets replaced text as 0101 etc. Is it because of the content in datas. How can I read the file as string. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What is the type of the file?

Comment: What is the file encoding?

Comment: file is docx and I havent done any file encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read data from a word with format using the OpenXML Format SDK with c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477500/how-do-i-read-data-from-a-word-with-format-using-the-openxml-format-sdk-with-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*.docx` is a file format which in raw view represents xml document. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) to become more familiar with this format definition.

For working with office formats Microsoft recommends to use `Open Xml SDK` at `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` library.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255.aspx) is a great article for learning how to work with Word files.
It works as follows:

```
using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(string.Empty, false))
{
    var body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    var text = body.GetFirstChild<Paragraph>().InnerText;
}
```

Also, take a look at this SO question: [How do I read data from a word with format using the OpenXML Format SDK with c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477500/how-do-i-read-data-from-a-word-with-format-using-the-openxml-format-sdk-with-c)

Comment: can I get the format (tables) unchanged while replacing

Comment: I know only that Open XML SDK allows to work with Word documents. I work with it only with Excel files and can not help you with specific Word information